# "Failed to load the key" error in Jenkins, not sure why or what this means

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to set up Jenkins locally on my Macbook, and after installation and unlocking, I put together a very basic job where I would echo "Hello World", but I keep getting this error in the stack trace when I run the build:

```
org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.60.3.jar!/hudson/model/Run/console.jelly:65:27: <j:whitespace> Failed to load the key: hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.consoleAnnotator
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:745)
```

I haven't the foggiest idea of what this could be referring to and I have yet to come across anything online that points me to a potential answer.  The only thing I have seen that is even marginally related refers to the Subversion not being current, but I am pretty confident that I have the correct versions of all of the required packages, plugins, etc.  I also really don't have any real experience with Jenkins, so I could very well have missed something, but I followed the instructions to the letter.  Could this be a permissions thing?  I tried asking folks in the Jenkins IRC channel but no dice.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a version of Java in your local machine ????

Comment: 1.8.0_144 is the version of Java I am have locally